# Как ускорить(оптимизировать) запрос к MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос, оптимизация

Я новичок в программировании, поэтому прошу не сильно пинать за вопрос, спрашиваю стараясь

Вопрос следующий:

1. Есть БД MySQL. Версия клиента базы данных: libmysql - 5.6.43
2. Есть таблица событий `notes_all`. Результат запроса `SHOW CREATE TABLE notes_all`:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `notes_all` (
   `id` char(26) NOT NULL,
   `type` text NOT NULL,
   `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `entity_type` text NOT NULL,
   `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `created_at` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `value_after` json NOT NULL,
   `value_before` json NOT NULL,
   `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `_links` json NOT NULL,
   `_embedded` json NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `id_2` (`id`),
   KEY `id` (`id`),
   KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
   KEY `created_by` (`created_by`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf
   ```

В конечном итоге я хочу получить метки времени (timestamp) событий, после которых в течении получаса не было никаких событий.

Т.е. в конечном итоге нужно:

```
created_by | created_at | count_events
```

где count_events - количество иных событий в течении получаса после этого события.

Идеально, конечно, если будут выбраны только события, в которых count_events равен 0.

Составляю запрос (тут $dateStart - timestamp начала месяца, $dateEnd - timestamp конца месяца):

```
SELECT `created_by`,`created_at`, (
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        `notes_all` as n
    WHERE
        n.created_at > notes_all.created_at AND n.created_at < (notes_all.created_at + 30 * 60) AND n.`created_by` = notes_all.created_by
    GROUP BY n.`created_by`
  ) as count_events
FROM
  `notes_all`
WHERE 
  `notes_all`.`created_at` >= ".$dateStart." and 
  `notes_all`.`created_at` <= ".$dateEnd
```

Получаю:
[image: Результат запроса выше]

Получаю полный список всех событий, где в столбце count_events, указано количество событий в течении получаса, следующего за указанным событием. Т.е. получаю почти то, что нужно (за исключением фильтрации только по нулевым событиям в столбце count_events)

Этот запрос всё правильно считает, но он безумно медленный. 25 строк считает в среднем за 4 секунды. Можно ли как-то получить тот же результат, кратно ускорив выполнение запроса?

Comment: *Есть таблица событий `notes_all` со структурой* Замените словесное описание на **полный** результат выполнения `SHOW CREATE TABLE notes_all;`. *Есть БД MySQL* Покажите результат выполнения `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо! Добавил в описание результат выполнения `SHOW CREATE TABLE notes_all;`

Comment: @Mike, Спасибо за Ваш ответ! Сейчас пробую сделать объединение через join.

Comment: @Mike выполнил Ваши рекомендации. Делаю вот такой запрос `SELECT id,created_by, created_at, count(id) FROM notes_all
GROUP BY created_by, created_at` Получаю вот такой ответ http://prntscr.com/xmdb3d. Получаю группировку по created_by и created_at, но это не то что нужно, т.к. в столбце count нужно видеть количество событий за полчаса а не в эту же секунду.

Comment: А версия MySQL - военная тайна? Между прочим, для описываемой задачи эта информация критична.

Comment: @Akina, да что Вы. Если это Важно))) `Версия клиента базы данных: libmysql - 5.6.43`

Comment: @Mike, к сожалению Ваш запрос выполняется овердолго. Даже с лимитом 2 - http://prntscr.com/xn1kfd

Comment: Нужна версия самой БД, а не клиента. Akina видимо хотел предложить что то оконными функциями, за один проход таблицы. А мне бы хотелось увидеть план выполнения (explain "ваш-запрос") причем и вашего варианта и мего

Comment: @Akina, `Select version()` вернул `5.7.32-cll-lve`.

Comment: Версия старая, оконные функции недоступны. Мысль останавливается...

Comment: @Mike Мой запрос запрос http://prntscr.com/xn344r, Ваш запрос http://prntscr.com/xn38hi

Comment: @Akina, в любом случае спасибо)

Comment: А вообще, смотря на планы выполнения могу сказать, что все таки стоило бы сделать составной индекс из двух колонок `(created_by, created_at)` это ускорит как любой из вариантов с join/подзапросами так и мой (индекс по одной колонке created_by при этом можно убрать)

Comment: @Mike, я последовал Вашей рекомендации и создал индекс двух колонок `(created_by, created_at)`. В результате мой запрос ускорился с 4 секунд до 0,12 секунд. Это фантастический результат, однако с ростом выборки информации в моём запросе растёт время выполнения. Сейчас пытаюсь разобраться с Вашим запросом. Идея, о том, что нет необходимости считать количество событий, если есть хотя бы одно, крайне интересная.

Comment: @Mike, я разобрался с Вашим запросом. Это именно то, что нужно. Он очень быстрый. Теперь я получаю 25 строк за `0.2239 секунды`, а 500 строк за `0.2251 секунды`. Спасибо, что вникли в суть задачи и предложили нестандартное решение. Как я могу Вас отблагодарить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IF(@prev_by=created_by, @prev_at-created_at, NULL) diff,
       @prev_by:=created_by AS created_by, @prev_at:=created_at
  FROM (SELECT @prev_by:=NULL, @prev_at:=NULL) x, notes_all
 WHERE notes_all.created_at >= $dateStart AND notes_all.created_at <= $dateEnd
 ORDER BY created_by, created_at DESC
```

Запрос считает разницу во времени между идущими друг за другом событиями по одному пользователю. Если в обрабатывамом окне нет более позних событий дает NULL. Основан на запоминании пользователя и времени события в пременных и использовании их при обработке следующей строки. Поэтому для запроса важна сортировка (по пользователю и дате в обратном порядке).

При необходимости можно обернуть его в внешний запрос и проверить diff на нужную разность `select * from (запрос указанный выше) x where diff < 30 * 60`

Comment: Да, это то что нужно.   Мой запрос теперь выглядит вот так и выполняется супербыстро `SELECT created_by, created_at, diff FROM( SELECT IF(@prev_by=created_by, @prev_at-created_at, NULL) diff, @prev_by:=created_by AS created_by, @prev_at:=created_at as created_at FROM (SELECT @prev_by:=NULL, @prev_at:=NULL) x, notes_all WHERE notes_all.created_at >= 1609794000 AND notes_all.created_at <= 1611608399 AND notes_all.created_by != 0 ORDER BY created_by, created_at DESC) pod where diff > 30*60`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

1. События, после которых в течении получаса не было никаких событий

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM notes_all t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM notes_all t2
                   WHERE t2.created_at BETWEEN  t1.created_at AND t1.created_at + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE )
-- WHERE t1.created_at BETWEEN @start AND @end
```

2. Количество событий в течение 30 минут после события

```
SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*)
FROM notes_all t1
LEFT JOIN notes_all t2 
    ON t2.created_at BETWEEN  t1.created_at AND t1.created_at + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
-- WHERE t1.created_at BETWEEN @start AND @end
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Comment: @Akita, подскажите, должен ли я как-то править информацию в Ваших запросах. Я попробовал Ваш 1 запрос - он напрочь вешает БД. Вероятно, я что-то делаю не так.

Comment: @Ярослав Понимаете, все запросы (и мои в том числе) однозначно фуллскан. Никакие индексы там не используются - потому что селективность запроса просто никакая. Если бы поставленная задача была основной и практически единственной на этой таблице, я бы вообще предложил изменить структуру таблицы, добавить в неё generated spatial column и соответствующий индекс.